# permission denied using vim in linux

Tags: linux, permissions

How do I change the user back to user space instead of root?

I accidentally edit my code as root and then the user name changes from "yuki" to "root".  After that, I could not edit my code as "yuki" anymore...

before:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuki yuki  5777 Apr 10 14:24 Makefile
```

after:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root     5828 Apr 24 19:42 Makefile
```

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: belongs on [SU], doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As root use:

```
chown yuki:yuki Makefile
```

to change owner back.

Comment: Hi Michael, after I used your command, it changes to "-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuki root 5777 Apr 10 14:24 Makefile".  How do I change both yukis back?  Thanks.

Comment: Use chown yuki:yuki - the last part is the group name